# Xcode 9 - Xcodebuild error - UI tests not running, Timed out waiting for AX loaded notification

Tags: ios, xcode9, xctest, xcodebuild, ios-ui-automation

My tests do not start executing, and always timeout every time I try to use an xcodebuild command.

The command that I used is the following:

```
xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme 'AppName' -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration 'UI_Automation' CODE_SIGN_STYLE='Manual' CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='iPhone Developer: John Smith (XXXXXXXX)' PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER='John Smith PP Name' DEVELOPMENT_TEAM='ABC Company Apple DEV' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=11.2' -destination-timeout 600 -only-testing:AppUITests clean test
```

It goes through a process where the app is built, but then the tests do not start executing. As a matter of fact, the Simulator does not even start, and I get the following error.

```
Testing failed:
Timed out waiting for AX loaded notification If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-60333F56-66CA-4C34-8460-3846DCF59C14/AppUITests-F74C4FDD-17EE-44AD-A2BA-DDB1BC0A1D7E/Session-AppUITests-2017-12-28_150211-qwlao1.log
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have been racking my brain around this for the past 2 weeks and can't figure it out.

Comment: Can someone please have a look?

Comment: @Jonh Smith i have added an answer for this. Please let me know your feedback and comment here if you face any difficulty implementing this

Comment: i have updated the answer .please accept and upvote it as it solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xcode build command changed since xcode 9. So you have to change your build command.

Follow the mentioned steps:

- First build the project. Command for build app is

  ```
  xcodebuild build-for-testing -workspace "Your.xcworkspace" -scheme "UpgradeAll" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air,OS=11.0" -derivedDataPath "All"
  ```
- Then execute the test command using this.

  ```
  xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun "All/Build/Products/UpgradeAll_iphonesimulator11.0-x86_64.xctestrun" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air,OS=11.0" '-only-testing:YourTestbundleName' -derivedDataPath 'build/reports/bundleName' | tee xcodebuild.log | ios-sim start --devicetypeid "iPad-Air, 11.0"
  ```

Comment: Thanks for replying to my comment. So the tests are still not starting up although the simulator does. I will see if there are any issues with the target, and reply back here. Thank you once again.

Comment: @JohnSmith Sure. i am waiting for your feedback

Comment: The first command worked fine. But the second one, I get BROKEN PIPE errors stemming from the xcpretty command. If I remove the xcpretty part, then it works fine. If you can just correct the second command, I'll be glad to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @john Smith i have edited the answer. You can accept it and upvofe it so that others can find it helpful.

Comment: Done, thanks. Can you also confirm how to use the above commands on a real device?

Comment: You are most welcome. I will let you know the procedure of testing real devices

Comment: I figured it out. There is something else that I need your help with. I observed that the "addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Push notifications")" listener to dismiss alerts does not work on Xcode 9/iOS 10 test executions. Do you happen to have a workaround for it?

Comment: It is a different issue. Please open a new question in different thread and lets discuss and try to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to run my UI Tests through jenkins. What I did was:

- Set up Jenkins as a Launch Agent instead of a daemon. (more info here https://medium.com/@ved.pandey/setting-up-jenkins-on-mac-osx-50d8fe16df9f)
- Grant the jenkins user admin privileges under System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Jenkins user -> 'Allow user to administer this computer'.

Rebooted my Mac Mini and the UI Tests work now.